# parametric formula for given curve

Tags: curves, parameter-estimation

I am just wondering, if such a curve can be described by one formula with some parameters?

[image]

I would think it would contain the exp function. I think this is related to [this](https://revisionscience.com/a2-level-level-revision/physics-level-revision/fields/capacitors). But can this be expressed as one formula? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like $y(t) = A(1-e^{-bt})[u(t-t_0)-u(t)]+A(1-e^{-bt_0})e^{-c(t-t_0)}u(t-t_0)$ where A, b and c are constants and $t_0$ is the time when the function starts to decrease. Here u(t) is the indicator function which is 1 when t>=0 and 0 for t<0.

Comment: This is most likely a solution of a DE of the form $\frac{dy}{dt}+ky=u(t-t_0)-u(t)$